# If a hidden creature attempts to attack another creature warded with the Sanctuary spell and fails the Wisdom save, is the warded creature alerted?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stealth

If a hidden creature attempts to attack another creature warded with the *sanctuary* spell and fails the Wisdom save, is the warded creature alerted?

If I'm wandering the woods as a monk with *sanctuary* and a rogue is chasing me, am I never gonna notice them until they hit me?

Comment: Hi Drake, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance. Thanks for telling us the game you're playing, but for future reference, the [dnd-5e] tag you used is our preferred way of specifying the game, hence I've removed it from the title. I've also included the title in the body, because it's good to have the question restated in the body rather than solely contained in the title; that said, if you're unhappy with my edits, feel free to [edit] your question the way you like it. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No, the warded creature would not be alerted.

I'll emphasize the key text from the [Sanctuary](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sanctuary#h-Sanctuary) spell:

> Until the spell ends, any creature who **targets** the warded creature
> with an attack or a harmful spell must **first** make a Wisdom saving
> throw.
>
> On a failed save, the creature must choose a new target or **lose the
> attack** or spell.

From your example, I'm assuming that the rogue has successfully *Hidden* from you since you imply that you don't know they're there.

If the Rogue fails their Wisdom save, then they are unable to target you. Since targeting happens *before* the actual attack, and since stealth is only broken as a result of an attack, they'd remain hidden.

Well, unless they did something else to break their stealth of course, such as jumping from the bushes yelling "DIE MONK SCUM!!".

Comment: Which monks can cast sanctuary?  ;)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Temple monks!  =P

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Open Hand Monk, beginning at level 11, are under the effects of a Sanctuary spell after a long rest.

Comment: @AlexMillette Good point; it's an interesting class feature, tranquility, given that way of the open hand monks are all about kicking and punching ... but I guess they can chill out until someone is unwise enough to attack them ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Unwise enough to attack them, but wise enough to pass the saving throw... That's a very specific level of wise (https://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=615) ;)